# How to Type in Input Field using javascript , to complete login procedure

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

[image]

[image]

[image]

while using
`document.getelement('').value=""` 
dosent work like it have typed something in the box , when we click on the box with mouse then its dispears

and following the complete thing like filling username , password , and clicking on login button not work due to this

how can we overcome this, i need to do this using java-script or any script which can execute on web

I tried to insert text into input box , but that dosent happens correctly like a normal written text

Comment: Instagram uses React. The inputs are probably controlled inputs, so they store the value. Changing just via the `value` property won't be enough. You'd have to modify the component's state.

Comment: @Spectric thanks for the guidance , but how can i do that like its just a sample i have to implement in other website 

to be more precised then i will tell you that i have a dashboard that i need id and pass to acess so i want that when someone acess the website it automatically login in the backend , so people sould not require to input id and pass

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instagram uses **React** and the inputs are [controlled inputs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components). It changes when you type **manually**. Changing the controlled input just by changing the `value` property won't work here because `onChange` event is not fired if you just change it my `.value`

If you are trying to do this then you can make **python** script through
[pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/).

Comment: Thanks for answering , but how can i do that like its just a sample i have to implement in other website to be more precised then i will tell you that i have a dashboard that i need id and pass to access so i want that when someone access the website it automatically login in the backend , so people should not require to input id and pass Thanks